# How is Double Din / 2 Din Audio System is better than Single Din

Tags: audio

How is `Double Din` / `2 Din Audio System` better than `Single Din`?
What are some scenarios where the Single Din Audio will prove to be more beneficial?

Appreciate if you can also highlight the very basic differences in the two.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between single and double DIN is the size of the unit.

However double DIN units often have added features like touch screens, dvd, and navigation features which require the extra space for mounting. Many double din units will use the same audio processors and DACs that the single din units of the same brand do, so they often have the same sound quality.

Often the advantage of going single DIN is that they are generally cheaper because they don't have the added bells and whistles of touch screens, etc. This means you can spend less money ($200-300) for a unit that has the exact same audio quality as a double din unit that costs $700+. Also a single din unit will fit in more vehicles than a double din.

Comment: A potential advantage of double DIN is more buttons, and thus less fiddling while driving. (I know, pull over if you're adjusting the radio--but on the other hand, radios should be designed so I can adjust them without looking at them. Bring back simple, tactile interfaces, I say.)

Answer (score 4):

The difference is solely in size. A double-DIN gives you more space, but at the end of the day what you should be looking at is what will fit in your car, and this may be hidden behind fascia.

My dash will only fit a double DIN, but because I have a single DIN sound system, I use the other half as a storage space.